# Proving $\sqrt{\frac{a}{ab+2c}}+\sqrt{\frac{b}{bc+2a}}+\sqrt{\frac{c}{ca+2b}}\ge \frac{3}{2}$ for $ab+bc+ca=2.$

Tags: inequality

Given non-negative real numbers $a,b,c$ satisfying $ab+bc+ca=2.$ Prove that$$\sqrt{\frac{a}{ab+2c}}+\sqrt{\frac{b}{bc+2a}}+\sqrt{\frac{c}{ca+2b}}\ge \frac{3}{2}.$$
Equality holds iff $a=2,b=1,c=0$ and its cyclic permutations.

It makes classical approachs hard to use.

I've tried to use the initial constrait $ab+bc+ca=2$ but it's possible lead to nothing. $$ab+2c=ab+c(ab+bc+ca)=ab(c+1)+c^2(a+b).$$
Consider the case $abc=0.$ WLOG, assuming $c=0; ab=2.$ Now, the OP is $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}+\frac{b}{2}=2\cdot\frac{1}{2\sqrt{b}}+\frac{b}{2}\ge \frac{3}{2}.$$
In case $abc>0.$ The OP is written as $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\sqrt{b+\dfrac{2c}{a}}}\ge \frac{3}{2}.$$

I don't know how to continue it. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

By Holder inequality, we have
\begin{align*}
 &\left(\sqrt{\frac{a}{ab+2c}}+\sqrt{\frac{b}{bc+2a}}+\sqrt{\frac{c}{ca+2b}}\right)^2
 \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} a^2(ab + 2c)\\[6pt]
 \ge{}& (a + b + c)^3.
\end{align*}

It suffices to prove that
$$(a + b + c)^3 \ge \frac94 \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} a^2(ab + 2c). \tag{1}$$

(1) is true which is verified by *Mathematica*.
I have a proof below.

Let $p := a + b + c, q := ab + bc + ca = 2, r := abc$. From $p^2 \ge 3q$, we have $p \ge \sqrt{6}$.

(1) is written as
$$p^3 - 9p - \frac94 pr + 9 + \frac{27}{2} r
\ge (a^2b + b^2c + c^2a)( 9p/4 - 9/2). \tag{2}$$

We use @d8g3n1v9's trick. We have
$$ab(a - 2b)^2 + bc(b - 2c)^2 + ca(c - 2a)^2 \ge 0$$
which is written as
$$4p^2 q + pr - 9q^2 \ge 3p (a^2b + b^2c + c^2a)$$
which yields
$$a^2b + b^2c + c^2a \le \frac{8p^2 + pr - 36}{3p}. \tag{3}$$

From (2) and (3), using $p \ge \sqrt{6}$, it suffices to prove that
$$p^3 - 9p - \frac94 pr + 9 + \frac{27}{2} r
\ge \frac{8p^2 + pr - 36}{3p} \cdot ( 9p/4 - 9/2)$$
or equivalently
$$2(p^2 - 6)(p - 3)^2 - 6p(p - 5)r \ge 0. \tag{4}$$

If $p \le 5$, clearly (4) is true.

If $p > 5$, using $q^2 \ge 3pr$, we have
$$2(p^2 - 6)(p - 3)^2 - 6p(p - 5)r
\ge 2(p^2 - 6)(p - 3)^2 - 6p(p - 5)\cdot \frac{2^2}{3p} > 0.$$

We are done.